# How do i remove the DC component from an audio signal using Matlab2016?

Tags: speech-processing, speech

I have been doing speech processing in matlab2016, and am stack on how to remove DC component. I tried using the the function `y=x-x(mean)` but it seems not to workout.

Comment: What do you mean by the fact it doesn’t work?

Comment: Could you try `y=x-mean(x)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `y = detrend(x,'constant')` in Matlab. This is to remove your so-called DC component.